# Can switch case being used like a void method?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Usually I will implement switch case in a method that return particular object. Something like below:

```
private string testing(string input){
    switch(input)
    {
        case "a":
        {
            ....
            return "TestingResult";
        }
        case "b":
        {
            ....
            return "TestingResultB";
        }
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to write a switch case for value assignment purpose? Something like below:

```
private string testing(string input){
    string TEST="";
    switch(input)
    {
        case "a":
        {
            ....
            TEST = "TestingResult";
        }
        case "b":
        {
            ....
            TEST = "TestingResultB";
        }
        default:
    }
    return TEST;
}
```

Of cause it can be achieve by simple If-Else statement, this question is for me to understand more functionality of switch case

Of course, after testing it, I receive error

```
control cannot fall through from one case label('case: "a"') to another
```

Comment: Why not just run it? Your code is all there. Just remove the ellipsis...

Comment: You can write any code (syntactically correct code, that is) in the case blocks (between the curly braces). Also, curly braces for a *case* statement are not always required (however often they are recommended).

Comment: @PaulSasik: Yeap I ran it, and get the error, sorry that I've missed out to include it

Comment: Ahh, you need to add a **break** statement at the end of a case block. Hard to see that it is not there if one is used to write it while coding without actually thinking about it ;)

Comment: The reason the `break` statements weren't required before: returning something implicitly breaks you out of the switch statement (and the entire function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. You just have to remember to put a 'jump' statement of some kind (this includes `break`, `goto case`, `return`, or `throw`), after each `case` label:

```
private string testing(string input){
    string TEST="";
    switch(input)
    {
        case "a":
            TEST = "TestingResult";
            break;
        case "b":
            TEST = "TestingResultB";
            break;
    }
    return TEST;
}
```

Note, the braces here are unnecessary, and the default isn't required in this construction as it will fall through the switch block if it doesn't match any of the cases.

**Further Reading**

- [switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `break;` in each case

```
private string testing(string input){
    string TEST="";
    switch(input)
    {
        case "a":
            TEST = "TestingResult";
            break;
        case "b":
            TEST = "TestingResultB";
            break;
        default:
    }
    return TEST;
}
```

As others have mentioned, the braces within each case are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is perfectly legitimate, however there is no point doing the value assignment unless you are going to carry on and do some further operations with it before returning.

To help you with becoming more proficient with switch/case statements:

- in your first example you don't need the default, just have a final return at the end of the function
- in your second example, you don't need the default at all - you do nothing with it
- a switch/case is usually used for multiple options, for example 4 or more. Any less than that and an if/else is equally readable. You should also bear in mind that a switch/case can give you good speed improvements in some cases

Comment: Meaning switch/case not only improve readability but also improve performance as well?

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep Yes. switch/case statements are compiled as a jump table, whereas if/else statements are compiled as test/else test/else test/etc. With only a few items you won't notice the speed improvement, but with larger numbers of options you will.